# При появлении модального окна исчезает, практически, весь контент страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Не могу понять причину. Сохраняется только то, что находится на странице в текущем положении скролла. Если прокрутить скролл вниз - ничего нет. 
Модальное окно bootstrap
http://energy-shop.com.ua/
[image: скрин]

```
 <?php include_once "header.php" ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main-table" id="yak1">
        <div class="user-block">
            <h1>Сетевые солнечные батареи</h1>
            <span>Расчитать стоимость</span>
            <span>Оставьте свой телефон <br>и мы с Вами свяжемся</span>
            <form id="call_back">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_top" placeholder="Имя" required>
                    <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone_top" placeholder="Телефон" required>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Отправить</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="modal-send" data-backdrop="true" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body request">
                            Сообщение отправлено
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




  .wrapper {
    max-width: 1974px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(21,47,67,1) 31%, rgba(21,47,67,1) 36%, rgba(16,35,56,1) 100%); /* ff3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(31%, rgba(21,47,67,1)), color-stop(36%, rgba(21,47,67,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(16,35,56,1))); /* safari4+,chrome */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(21,47,67,1) 31%, rgba(21,47,67,1) 36%, rgba(16,35,56,1) 100%); /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(21,47,67,1) 31%, rgba(21,47,67,1) 36%, rgba(16,35,56,1) 100%); /* opera 11.10+ */
}
.header-top {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.logo-block img {
    margin: 8px 0 0 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.contact-block {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.address-index {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
.email {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
}
.address {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 57px;
}
.phone-number {
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.phone-number img {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -38px;
    width: 31px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.phone-number span {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav-block {
    margin-top: 6px;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
.nav-block img {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
}
.main-table {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url(../img/solar-1-min.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}


.navbar {
    background: #021c48;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar li {
    margin-right: 35px;
}
.navbar li a {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #fff!important;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.navbar li:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eed329;
}
.user-block{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 140px 170px 0 0;
}
.user-block .btn-default {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.user-block h1, .user-block span {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}
.user-block > span:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.user-block span:nth-child(2n) {
    font-family: 'ralewaybold', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.user-block h1 {
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.user-block .form-group {
    margin-left: 287px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.user-block .form-control {
    width: 125%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.modal-open .modal {
    margin-top: 150px;
}

$("#call_back").on("submit", function (e) {
        var nameForm = $("#name_top").val();
        var phoneForm = $("#phone_top").val();
        $.ajax({
            url : "mail.php",
            method : "GET",
            data : {
                name : nameForm,
                phone : phoneForm
            },
            dataType : "json",
            success : function (data) {
                $(".request").html(data.message);
                $("#modal-send").modal('show');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Весь код, который необходим для решения вашей проблемы, должен быть в теле вопроса.

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Comment: Нужно ли отправлять весь код с сайта? Весь html и css, js?